# How do I get the touchpad on an ASUS N56VZ working properly?

Tags: 12.04, touchpad, asus, grab-handles

I just got my new Asus laptop today, and after installing Ubuntu I experienced some weird mouse behaviour, at least a new behaviour to me. It seems the mouse is in Mac-theme, no right clicking but two-finger tapping etc. I also see, what I would call, anchor points around the windows, I would like those gone.

Left-clicking and dragging, e.g., a scroll bar does not work, as the area that gets pressed down is a part of the touchpad. Since multitouch is not supported, clicking with one finger and dragging with another does not work.

For clarification, both buttons behaves like left click.

Laptop is an ASUS N56VZ

[image: Anchor points]

Comment: Can you add the model # of the laptop to your post?

Comment: Model added! :)

Answer (score 2):

I have the same computer, and Ubuntu has added some cool multi-touch features that you seem to have discovered (the same way I did!) by accident.

- a one finger touch works as a left click
- a two finger touch works as a right click
- a three finger touch brings up what you see in the picture you posted, a quick way to move or resize a window
- a four finder touch brings up dash
- a one finger touch in the top right corner acts as a middle click (for example, doing this over a hyperlink in a browser opens the link in a new tab).

There are a couple of gestures and other things that you can do with three or four fingers, you can see the list at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch.

You can still press on the touchpad for normal left and right clicks like you do on a Mac, just make sure you press down at the bottom of the touchpad, that's the only part that will move (again like a Mac). You can also click and drag by pressing the touchpad this way.

Hope this helped!

Comment: I have the same kind of computer. This was helpful but click & drag still doesn't work. ASUS N56V.